# Group by multiple entities columns and perform rolling average and rolling standard deviation

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a "large" mixed dataset. Its structure is shown below:

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
  RangeIndex: 8667486 entries, 0 to 8667485
  Data columns (total 7 columns):
  src         uint16
  dst         uint16
  seq         uint64
  signal      uint8
  noise       uint8
  bitrate     float32
  snr         int16
  dtypes: float32(1), float64(1), int16(1), uint16(2), uint64(1), uint8(2)
  memory usage: 231.4 MB
```

What I would like to achieve is to group by `src`, `dst` and `bitrate`, then do standard deviation and mean of rolling average over the groups. For the grand finale, I would like to add it back to the original DataFrame. I need it as one of a ML features.

I'm not sure if this is even a right path, but this is where it stops for me:

```
df.groupby(['src', 'dst', 'bitrate'])[['snr']].rolling(w_size).mean()
```

and

```
df.groupby(['src', 'dst', 'bitrate'])[['snr']].rolling(w_size).std()
```

The result is a MultiIndex DataFrame and I have no idea how to add it to the original Dataframe.

I assume that ordering by sequence number has also to be done somewhere in the code for the correctness of the rolling average.

Answer (score -1):

If you make `dfgrouoed.reset_index()` it will return a single indexed dataframe